# RuntimeError: the sip module implements API v11.0 but the PyQt4.QtCore module requires API v11.1

Tags: python, macos, pyqt, gnuradio, python-sip

I'm trying to install gnuradio from this repo, using homebrew.  I'm on OSX 10.10.2.

The install keeps failing and saying that my sip and pyqt modules ahave mismatched API versions.

I've done some searching and most things seem to indicate that I should remove sip as well as pyqt, then install sip, and build pyqt against that.

I've tried this approach several times using `brew uninstall sip` and `brew uninstall pyqt` then reinstalling them and it doesn't seem to work.

```
   ==> python setup.py install --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/gnuradio/HEAD/libexec
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 251, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 558, in get
    raise self._value
RuntimeError: the sip module implements API v11.0 but the PyQt4.QtCore module requires API v11.1
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: " from this repo" which repo?

Comment: Whoops, sorry about that.  The insanity of debugging and posting on message boards, looks like I posted this in the wrong place.

Comment: so, *which* repo then?

Comment: From the gnuradio repo.  My error is different now though - it compiles ok, but is getting this `Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread` when I run the companion.  Have messed with [this patch](https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/pull/604/files) after doing some posting on the gnuradio mailing list, but it didn't help :-(

Comment: :( I can file your pain; For future reference [here's the mailing list thread](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/discuss-gnuradio/2015-10/msg00016.html) you mention.

Comment: Yeah.  Further notes - I did the offline patch that Michael recommended on that thread, and it didn't seem to work.  Also, I went and looked at the actual homebrew formula for gnuradio and it *should* be applying that patch during the install anyway.  So not sure where the problem lies.